# How can I use a cell's content for a column index?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, cell, excel-indirect

For example, in cell M1, I store the column index (`A` or `B` or `C`...) that I want to use later.

If now I put character `D` in M1, by using `=SUM($M$1:$M$1)`, I want to get the summation of column D. And if I change `D` to `A` in M1, I want the summation of column A instead.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully `=SUM(INDIRECT(M1&":"&M1))` will serve.

Comment: Personally, I'm finding that we have to be more assertive in our answers. If we say "try this" or "this might work" it can be marked down. If we've misunderstood the question we always have the option to delete or correct. Regards.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. It works fine. One more question is that, if the column index stored in M1 is not in the same worksheet, but in 'Book2', what should I do? I tried my luck, but failed.

Comment: Thanks so much. That's really beyond my expectation. I tried "=sum(book1!indirect(M1&":"&M1))" and "=sum(indirect(book1!M1&":"&M1))". No luck. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @pnuts, sorry, I am stupid, I wanted to say is "sheet1" instead of "book1". The sheet1 is in the same workbook, and sure it is open. May I know how?

Comment: no, I think I am not making myself clear. I have one sheet "MainFrame", where M1 is in. And there is another sheet "rawData". I store D in M1 (in MainFrame), and now I wanna get the summation of column D of "rawData".

Comment: I wanna have it done in MainFrame, so I am wondering where to put "rawData!"

Comment: @pnuts, that works!! Thank you, and thank you all. I am a programmer, and new to dataprocessing with excel. Sorry for the naive question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option without the `INDIRECT`. Unlike @pnut's, it will only work for columns A to Z (or L in this case), but since you're basing it off M1, maybe that's okay:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:L,0,CODE(UPPER(M1))-64))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have columns beyond Z. Your option is really interesting :)